# How to configure VMWare Workstation in Linux to accept RDP connections

Tags: linux, rdp, vmware-workstation, ubuntu-10.04

My virtual machine in VmWare Workstation is refusing RDP connections. On my other VM it was able to accept connections. I had to add some entries into the .VMX file in order to get it to work, but I forgot what I put in there and the file has already been deleted.

Comment: What OS is the guest VM? What Networking do you have set up for the Guest (NAT, bridged, host)?

Comment: The OS is Windows 7, and VMware is set up as bridged.

Answer (score 2):

Check the following:

- Windows is set up to allow Remote desktop (System Properties)
- Windows firewall is allowing remote desktop connections
- Your host OS is allowing remote desktop connections through the firewall

Do you have VMWare tools installed? Can you ping both ways (host to guess, and vice versa)?

AFAIK, you should not have to change anything in the .vmx file to allow RDP connections, as long as your network connection is bridged.

Answer (score 0):

As Sagar said

check this

http://img829.imageshack.us/img829/9255/captureag.jpg

Regards

Alexandre